# Query parquet file with DuckDB throws Runtime Error: "Payload value bigger than allowed. Corrupted file?"

Tags: parquet, duckdb

I am using DuckDB to query a parquet file. The query is like:

```
SELECT * FROM 'yellowcab.parquet' limit 5;
```

DuckDB throws Runtime Error: `Payload value bigger than allowed. Corrupted file?`. And it doesn't seem to be an issue in the parquet file because I can read it with other tools like `parquet-tools` and `parquet-cli`.

The parquet file can be downloaded with `wget https://github.com/guihaojin/duckdb/raw/master/yellowcab.parquet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in DuckDB and it's fixed in https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/pull/3234.